# h3 tag outputs 2 lines and Font Awesome icon is not showing

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a problem in HTML5 `<h3>` tag and Font Awesome icon's tags beside that.

Let me walk you through the problem. First things first, this is my code for a product selection page. It contains large scale Font Awesome icon's and `<h3>` tag under each icon. Of course the page is divided in Bootstrap 4 grids to two columns. Each column contains the icon and the text but the first problem is when typing the value of `<h3>` tag; in the second column it output in two lines.

By that I mean:

[image: PC]

The second problem is the most of Font Awesome icons is not showing not even a box.

main.php

```
<?
?>
<html>
<head><title></title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="mainstyle.css">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=yes">
<link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.2/css/bootstrap-combined.no-icons.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/3.2.1/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>
<body>
<style>
.padding-0{
    padding-right:0;
    padding-left:0;
}
.padding-1{
    padding-right:0;
    padding-left:1px;
}
</style>
<!-- Bootstrap Jquery JavaScripts  -->
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-J6qa4849blE2+poT4WnyKhv5vZF5SrPo0iEjwBvKU7imGFAV0wwj1yYfoRSJoZ+n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-wfSDF2E50Y2D1uUdj0O3uMBJnjuUD4Ih7YwaYd1iqfktj0Uod8GCExl3Og8ifwB6" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<!-- Bootstrap Jquery JavaScripts  -->
<!-- Navbar Bootstrap 4 -->
<nav class="navbar navbar-light navbar-fixed-top pulse-header">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-nav-left">
        <li class="nav-item"><a href="#" class="open-pulse-sidebar"><i class="ion-grid pulse-icons"></i></a></li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav float-xs-right">
        <li class="nav-item"><a href="#" class="toggle-search"><i class="ion-ios-search-strong pulse-icons"></i></a></li>
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a href="#" class="open-notification-sidebar">
                <i class="ion-earth pulse-icons"></i>
                <span class="pulse-circle"></span>
            </a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item"><a href="#" class="open-chat-sidebar"><i class="ion-chatboxes pulse-icons"></i></a></li>
    </ul>
    <img src="https://jsfiddle.net/img/logo.png" class="m-sm-auto">
</nav>

<!-- Main Page for Pharmacy Order Selection -->
    <div class="row">
    <!-- color:#3AAFA9 -->
        <div class="col-sm-6 padding-0">
            <div class="container cont">
                <div class="content content">
                    <div style="font-size: 100px;">
                        <i class="fa fa-medkit fa-2x hover"></i>
                        <br>
                        <h3 class="drugs">أدوية</h3>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-6 padding-1">
            <div class="container cont">
                <div class="content content">
                    <div style="font-size: 100px;">
                        <i class="fas fa-tablets fas-2x hover"></i> <!--- here font awesome icon not showing -->
                        <br>
                        <h3 class="medicalequi">معدات طبية</h3>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
<!--- Main Page Order Selection latest Tag -->
</body>
</html>
```

Css Code : [mainstyle.css]

```
@font-face {
    font-family: "hana";
    src: url("fonts/hana.ttf");
}
@media screen and (max-width : 1500px) {
    .hover {
        color:#FEFFFF;
        position: absolute;
        top:-100px;
        left:-50px;
        transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
    }
    .drugs{
        position:absolute;
        left:20px;
        font-family:hana;
        color:#FEFFFF;
        transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
    }
    .medicalequi{
        position:absolute;
        right:-130px;
        font-family:hana;
        color:#FEFFFF;
        transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
    }
    .cont{
        background-color:#17252A;
        height:43rem;
    }

}

@media screen and (min-width: 320px) and (max-width: 480px) {
      .hover {
        color:#FEFFFF;
        position: absolute;
        top:-280px;
        left:-220px;
        transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
    }
      .drugs{
        position:absolute;
        left:-150px;
        top:-40px;
        font-family:hana;
        color:#FEFFFF;
        transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
    }
      .medicalequi{
        position:absolute;
        left:-150px;
        top:-40px;
        font-family:hana;
        color:#FEFFFF;
        transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
    }
      .cont{
        background-color:#17252A;
        height:25rem;
    }
}


.content {
  position: absolute;
  left: 300px;
  top: 344px;
}

.hover:hover{
color:#DEF2F1;
cursor:grab;
transform: scale(1.2);
}
.medicalequi:hover{
color:#DEF2F1;
cursor:grab;
transform: scale(2.5);
}

.drugs:hover{
color:#DEF2F1;
cursor:grab;
transform: scale(2.5);
}
/*  CSS for Navbar */
.pulse-header {
  height: 60px;
  min-height: 60px;
  max-height: 60px;
  background-color: #1f2532;
  padding: 13px 15px;
}

.pulse-header .navbar-nav-left {
  margin-left: 0px;
}

.pulse-header .nav > .nav-item {
  margin-right: -50px;
}

.pulse-header .nav > .nav-item > a {
  position: relative;
}

.navbar img {
    margin: 0px auto;
    display:block;
}
```

Last thing is a bootstrap 4 responsive Navbar. I want a example for a navbar the contains more then 4 items 2 items shows when surfing from a smart mobile and all items shows in PC. How to align items like this?

Phones:

[image: phones]

Computer:

[image: computer]

Comment: your code is working fine . I checked

Comment: @nikhilsugandh really ? did you change anything ? i mean even the font awesome link tag works?

Comment: h3 tags outputs in same line i cant see anything in fa they are not visible even ehen the navbar is lighter

Comment: your code is not correct there shoulnt be any ul an dli inside navabar

Comment: what are you trying you trying to achieve

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Well for your first question, if you notice in one there is a single word and on second you have 2 words. So the width of h3 is just wrapping text to next line as it doesnt have enough space. Increase the width or reduce font size but extra would always be wrapped..
2. make sure your styles files are included properly (linkage). Secondly its is in relevant tag and you are not missing icon code.
3. Visit [w3Schools](https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap4/bootstrap_navbar.asp) you can find code there.

   Make sure to share some code that way you would be assisted much better. No body will code for  you. So for your 3rd question share code snippet next time that would help alot. For now you can use the above link to adjust it as per your requirements. :)